# Configure web.config to access website only using IE

Tags: asp.net, cross-browser

I want my website to be accessed only using IE 6.0 or above. If anyone tries to access the website using any other browser I want to display a big warning message. Is it possible to configure this in web.config insted of checking via javascript. I am assuming something like in authentication we have customErrors attribute were we can set the custome error page in case of failure to authenticate the user.
Thank You.
Krishnaraj

Comment: Why?  Why on earth would you even want to invest time in such a requirement?  I like IE personally, but people who like other browsers tend to be...  attached to their own favorite browser.  You'd be making an awful lot of people perturbed.  Most developers spend considerable time and energy enduring their sites look nice in alternate browsers...  You're going the other way on that.

Comment: We have an intranet application which is already in production and it was tested only in IE. Now we are getting lot of issues when it is used in other browsers. Until we fix this issue, we want to restrict the access from non-IE browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the HTTP_USER_AGENT header to see what's the browser that's submitting the request.
For I.E it would be like :

> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; **MSIE 7.0**;
>   Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; SLCC1;
>   .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC
>   5.0; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)

P.S: This header can be manipulated by the client and submitted to browser so it is not 100% reliable.
Am curious to know why you want to restrict users to I.E?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct support for this functionality.  However, you could validate the browser in an implementation of `IHttpHandler` and register that in web.config.